# Magento current cart detail(Without login)with product data

Tags: magento, cart

I have Magento online store with two types of products (configurable and simple) and now I am working on web services. Can someone explain me how to get cart detail without logging in? I have tried everything but I am unable to get cart details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cart item

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
if($cart->getAllItems()):
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item):
    echo $item->getProduct()->getName()
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: are you using the api to get the data?

Comment: Not getting recent cart item.. I m calling Main magento Mage file and getting data not using magento default API.

Comment: can you post ur code too so i can see what are you missing.

Comment: <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
require_once('../app/Mage.php') ;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

  $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote('70');
   if($cart->getAllItems()):

  foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item):
 print_r($item);
 echo $item->getProduct()->getName();
 endforeach;
  endif;

Comment: Bro still not working i m using magento V 1.9.2.4 $item not getting data.

Comment: `$pro=Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->load(//productid);` check you are getting the data. if yes then the problem is session

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::load(Array ( [0] => 9 ) )' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test8/lib/Varien/Object.php:653 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test8/json/ggg.php(10): Varien_Object->__call('load', Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test8/json/ggg.php(10): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->load('9') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test8/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 653

Comment: sorry my mistake `$pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(//productid);`

Comment: <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
require_once('../app/Mage.php') ;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

  $cart = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('9'); 
   if($cart->getAllItems()):

  foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item):
 print_r($item);
 echo $item->getProduct()->getName();
 endforeach;
  endif;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107317/discussion-between-rahul-prajapati-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

You will not get visitor's cart item from another resource as its interlinked with browser session. For this you need to add product from that resource from which you want to get. API is the suitable way for this. Please look at the below code i guess it will helps you.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$initializationCode = 'admin';
$initializationType = 'store';
Mage::app($initializationCode, $initializationType);

    /**
     * This is the path to the V2 wsdl of the magento api
     **/
    $wsdl = 'http://yoursite.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1';

    /**
     * Create the soap client
     **/
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => false));
    $username = 'mysoapuser';
    $password = 'mysoapuserpassword';

    /**
     * For every magento api session, we first need to login.
     * The returned value is you API session_id which you need to
     * Pass to every API call you make.
     **/
    $session_id = $client->login($username, $password);

    /**
     * The first thing we do is create the Magento shopping cart, or quote
     *
     * Here is detailed information and more examples from Magento:
     * http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html
     *
     * We pass it the session_id from our login call and the store id we want
     * create the quote for. The returned value will be the quote_id
     * if it was successful, or nothing with no faults if it fails
     *
     **/
    $cart = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session_id, '1');

    $addAddress = $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses(
        $session_id,
        $cart,
        array(
            array(
                'mode' => 'shipping',
                'firstname' => 'Paul',
                'lastname' => 'Briscoe',
                'street' => '117 N. 1st St.',
                'city' => 'Ann Arbor',
                'region' => 'MI',
                'postcode' => '48104',
                'country_id' => 'US',
                'telephone' => '7345458017',
                'is_default_shipping' => 1
            )
        )
    );   

        /**
         * Just make sure to check that the quoteId was returned from the API
         * Next we are going to start adding products into the new quote. The format is below.
         * Keep in mind that you could easily loop through an array of order products.
         *
         * Note: getExternalOrder() does not actually exist, but if you have an order object
         * or array of products you can use to get the info you need.
         **/

        $externalOrderProducts = getExternalOrder();
        $products = array();
        foreach($externalOrderProducts as $product){
            $products[] = array(
                'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'qty' => $product->getQty(),
                'options' => null,
                'bundle_option' => null,
                'bundle_option_qty' => null,
                'links' => null
            )
        } 

        /**
         * Here make the API call back to Magento to add the product array to the quote
         *
         * For more information on this call see:
         * http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html
         *
         * Returns True if the product successfully added to the quote
         **/

        if($addAddress) {
            $addProduct = $client->shoppingCartProductAdd(
                $session_id,
                $cart,
                array($products)
            );
        } else {
            echo "Address did not add.";
        }

        /**
         * Again, check that the product added successfully and then simply call the Shipping List API
         * For a list of available shipping methods for this quote.
         *
         * For more information on this call see:
         * http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.list.html
         *
         **/

         if($addProduct) {
             $shipping = $client->shoppingCartShippingList($session_id, $cart);
         } else {
             echo "Product did not add.";
         }

         echo "<pre>";
         var_dump($shipping);
         echo "</pre>";
//
```